# html select like build parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to setup a parameterized build project in Jenkins. I would like to create a choice parameter where for each option it should display StringX and it should supply CodeX as selected value to build as we have in html select:

```
<select...>
<option value='CodeX'>StringX</option>
</select>
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this?
Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: You could have a look at this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin)

Comment: I went thru it, but could not get how exactly it provides the above said feature.